# Maven + Grails + App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, maven-2, grails, groovy

Has anyone used **Maven**, **Grails**, and **App Engine** together?

I can use Maven with Grails and Grails with App Engine, but using them in concert gives me the following error:

```
The command 'grails run-app' is not supported with AppEngine. Use 'grails app-engine' to start the application
```

Is there any way to "pass through" the Maven goal to access **app-engine** plugin for grails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, the Maven Grails plugin does not support the features introduced by Grails [AppEngine Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/app-engine) yet. So, for now, you have to run (not sure what you mean by "pass through BTW):

```
grails app-engine run
```

Comment: By "pass through", I just meant a call like (I'm making this up) 'mvn grails:app-engine -dappEngineCommand=run' that I did not know about.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is nothing like this.

Answer (score 2):

In the command prompt, you can run:

```
mvn grails:exec -Dcommand="app-engine" -Dargs="run"
```

Which will do exactly what you want it to do.